# C++: How to make constructor for multidimensional vector?

Tags: c++, class, vector, multidimensional-array

I want to create two and three dimensional vectors using a constructor in a class. However, I do not know how for multidimensional vectors.

One dimensional works:

```
class One{
    public:
        vector < float > myvector;

        One(int length) : myvector(length){}

};
```

Two dimensional does not work:

```
class Two{
    public:
        vector < vector < float > > myvector;

        Two(int length, int width) : myvector(length)(width) {}

};
```

Three dimensional does not work either:

```
class Three{
    public:
        vector < vector < vector < float > > > myvector;

        Three(int length, int width, int height) : myvector(length)(width)(height) {}

};
```

The answer below works for two dimensional vector. I would expect the following code for three dimensional however it seems to be wrong

```
class Three{
    public:
        vector < vector <  vector < float > > > myvector;

        Three(int length, int width, int height) : myvector(length, vector<float>(width, vector<float>(height))) {}

};
```

Comment: ok, should be
Three(int length, int width, int height) : myvector(length, vector < vector <float> > (height, vector <float>(width))){}

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For the twodimensional case, it should be:

```
Two(int length, int width) : myvector(length, std::vector<float>(width)) {}
```

I’ll let you figure out the third case yourself.

Comment: Haha, you win the race this time. +1 :)